# when I change my account name in GitHub, the site(portfolio) that is deployed to Vercel.com should be changed automatically

Tags: github, next.js

I've deployed Next.js project(portfolio) to Vercel.com. In this project, some data get from GitHub profile info such as account name, location. So when I change my account name in GitHub, the site(portfolio) that is deployed to Vercel.com should be changed automatically. But it doesn't. What should I do to change it without redeployment?
GitHub URL: https://github.com/TrojanDeveloper/trojan-portfolio
Portfolio: https://trojan-portfolio.vercel.app/

When I do new commit and push to Github repository, the site(portfolio) that is deployed to Vercel is changed.

Comment: Why would a static site change automatically, without redeployment? Or without using Github api with Javascript?

Comment: Thanks for your attention, when I develop a new famous project, I want to display it at my portfolio, so the site that is deployed to Vercel has to be changed.

Comment: Like I said, you need to call github api using AJAX requests, on page load to get any "latest information" about your profile. Otherwise, you'll only see **static** content stored from the time your site deployed. Vercel doesn't matter; it's just hosting your app; Github Pages could do the exact same thing, and the answer would be the same without nextjs

Comment: I've done. I used revalidate method(ISR). Thank you for your help.

Comment: Feel free to post your solution below as an answer